# get_browser not showing ismobiledevice

Tags: php, iphone

I'm using the `ismobiledevice` value in the array that `get_browser()` returns to redirect users to the mobile version of a page. However, when I access the page from an iPhone, the `ismobiledevice` value doesn't come back as `1`. What could be the cause and how can I fix it?

Comment: i updated latest browsercap.ini, now works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe your browscap.ini doesn't contain the descriptions of iPhones/iPads.
Get a recent browscap.ini from e.g. http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp

Comment: is there any way to check , current browsercap.ini supporting device

Comment: yes, you can check by issuing get_browser and check the result, like you already do.

Comment: now i updated, i now am checking wiht get_browser function , that is $browser['ismobiledevice']==1 then redirect to mobile page else redirect to pc page, but dont know what is the reason, my page goes to un terminated redirect loop and finaly The page isn't redirecting properly

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing actual code. But probably that's another issue -> another question.